# Difference between returning a Collection versus an array back to frontend?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

**Background**

I am developing using the Laravel framework and most recently, had to retrieve some data from a SQL DB, spread across a couple of tables, and also required aggregating the results according to a certain column to facilitate easier presentation. As a generalised solution, I thought I could accomplish the task in at least 2 ways.

1. To write an Eloquent query involving ::where and ->groupBy amongst other operators
2. (The path which I took) To build an array of arrays

Either way, the result is then sent back to the show blade page.

**Question**

What are the implications of using each approach? Also, does passing back a Collection (a result of an Eloquent query) really mean you are passing all field data to the front end, even when most of it might not be used?

My thoughts include:

1. Using Eloquent seems much more elegant and I presume(?) more efficient. However, it seems that I will be passing objects with all their data when only a subset of these is required.
2. Contrary to above, building an array means i have to code manually but my array contains exactly what needs to be passed back to the frontend, nothing more.

Comment: Most elegant way is use `Resources` to pass data to the front end. Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resoaurces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to return the whole result set from the DB strait to the requester. You may do this in a very small project, or PoC, or while learning something. In other cases you need a layer to translate your results from the DB into resulting data. This layer is important also because lots of times the result from the DB is not the final data that I might need to return, so I may need to have some data processing/convertion/replacement prior return. How this layer is implemented - it depends.

> Using Eloquent seems much more elegant and I presume(?) more efficient. However, it seems that I will be passing objects with all their data when only a subset of these is required.

this is fast and "dirty" and will lead into problems in a long run. As you mentioned, Collection is an array of objects, and Collection instance itself is an traversable object, so you need to have a middleware to translate your objects into serializable presentation so the laravel can set that as a response. This already may be done for you behind the scene.

> Contrary to above, building an array means i have to code manually but my array contains exactly what needs to be passed back to the frontend, nothing more.

This is slower but you control what to return. If you do not have any abstractions for this translation layer and keep that job done in a controller - it will lead also into problems in a long run as it will be hard to maintain and refactor.

So, the approach with an abstraction translation layer is the best to go, but yes, it require some extra work to be done prior, it will take some time, but will give you better results in a long run